# Finding the distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> $\textbf{Problem}$ Let $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots$ be independent and identically distributed with 
>   \begin{align*}
> &P[Y_n=0]=\alpha\\
> &P[Y_n>y]=(1-\alpha)e^{-y}
> \end{align*}
>
> Define the random variables $X_n, n\geq 0$ by 
>   \begin{align*}
> &X_0=0\\
> &X_{n+1}=\alpha X_n+Y_{n+1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Prove that 
>   \begin{align*}
> &P[X_n=0]=\alpha^n\\ 
> &P[X_n>x]=(1-\alpha^n)e^{-x}
> \end{align*}

$\textbf{Attempt}$ Firstly, I found $X_n=\alpha^{n-1}Y_1+\cdots+\alpha Y_{n-1}+Y_n$.

If $X_n=0$ , then $Y_1=Y_2=\cdots =Y_n=0 $ since $Y_i \geq 0 $ for all $1\leq i \leq n$.

Thus, I got $P[X_n=0]=\alpha^n$.

However, I stuck how to $P[X_n>x]$ calculate...

Any help is appreciated... Thank you!

$\textbf{Update}$ I'll use induction.
If n=1, we can easily check that $P[X_n>x]=(1-\alpha^n)e^{-x}$

\begin{align*}
P[X_{n+1}>x] &= P[\alpha X_n+Y_{n+1}>x]\\ 
&=P[Y_{n+1}=0]P[\alpha X_{n}>x]+\int_{0}^x P[Y_{n+1}=t] P[\alpha X_n>x-t]dt +\int_x^{\infty} P[Y_{n+1}=t]dt \\
&(\textrm{because $ \alpha X_n +Y_{n+1}>x $ if $ Y_{n+1}>x $)}\\
&=\alpha(1-\alpha^n)e^{-\frac{x}{\alpha}}+\int_{0}^x (1-\alpha)e^{-t} (1-\alpha^n)e^{-\frac{x-t}{\alpha}}dt +\int_{x}^{\infty} (1-\alpha)e^{-t}dt \\
&=\alpha(1-\alpha^n)e^{-\frac{x}{\alpha}}+\alpha(1-\alpha^n)(e^{-x}-e^{-\frac{x}{\alpha}})+(1-\alpha)e^{-x}\\
&=(1-\alpha^{n+1}) e^{-x}
\end{align*}

I'm not sure my proof is right.....

Could you check my error in my proof?

Comment: I am pretty sure an inductive argument is the one you should look for

Comment: @Stan Tendijck Umm.... Then, we'll show that $P[X_{n+1}>x ] = (1-\alpha^{n+1})e^{-x}$. And, $P[X_{n+1}>x] = P[\alpha X_n + Y_{n+1} >x ]$. How to divide $P[\alpha X_n +Y_{n+1} >x]$??...

Comment: Do you know how convolution work, i.e., how you determine the distribution of $X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are some random variables?

Comment: I tried to calculate in 'Update'.... Could you see my attempt??

Comment: Looks right! Maybe worth noticing that you used $P(Y_{n+1}=t)=P(Y_{n+1}>t)$ which is true, if you view the left-hand side as the density of $Y_{n+1}$ at $t$.

Comment: For $t>0$ , $P[Y_{n+1} \leq t]= 1 - (1-\alpha) e^{-t} $. By differentiating with respect to $t$, we get $P[Y_{n+1} =t ] = P[Y_{n+1}>t]$!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative strategy notes that $Y_n$ has characteristic function $\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha}{1-it}=\frac{1-\alpha it}{1-it}$, so $X_n$ has characteristic function $\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{1-\alpha^{n-j+1}it}{1-i\alpha^{n-j}t}=\frac{1-\alpha^nit}{1-it}$ as required.